# Switch to POST from GET, need to submit a form to two different locations

Tags: javascript, html

[I did see the similar problems solved with AJAX/jQuery, so please read on].

I have a form that a user can fill out - but one of the options on the form allows selection of an image, and when the user goes to do that they are brought to a new page.

This was originally done via get, but my problem is... I need to save all of the information on the form to the session so that I can restore it when the user selects an image and goes back to the first page that had the form.

A HTTP GET may not hold enough data for all the information on my form, so I need to switch to post.

So, here's my problem... I need the form to POST to one page when I click "Select Image" and another when I click "Submit".  How can I get the form to POST to a different page depending on which button was clicked?

PS: I'd prefer to just use standard javascript/html here.  I plan on learning AJAX and moving over to jQuery after a while, but I'm not there yet :)

Comment: I think the question you're asking is this:  http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-action.phtml

Comment: AJAX is mostly also "standard javascript/html". I suggest looking at the jQuery ajax plugins.

Comment: http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/07/change-form-action-method-attributes.html - a completed script for you

Comment: So, you've already accepted an answer, but I have to ask: why isn't the "select an image" just a separate form? This lack of statelessness (however trivial now) is going to bite you in the butt later on.

Comment: I'll contemplate putting the image selection on another page after everything else has been submitted - but I don't think it would be viable to have two forms on the same specific page because then I'd lose the users information if they filled one out and submitted the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onclick`, let each button call different functions. Within these functions, change the action attribute of the form dynamically.

```
document.forms['yourform'].action = 'your intended page';
```

Then submit the form.

```
document.forms['yourform'].submit();
```